# Retry Configuration for @RabbitListener programatically specify dead-letter queue

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I've been trying to find a way to set a retry mechanism to all `@RabbitListener`'s. I've already tried with the properties:

```
listener:
  auto-startup: true
  concurrency: 1
  max-concurrency: 1
  retry:
    enabled: true
    initial-interval: 1000
    max-attempts: 3
    max-interval: 10000
    multiplier: 2
    stateless: true
```

And it works fine *with the only problem that no error is sent with the message*. The only problem I have is that in order to send the messages to a specific `DLQ` I have to change my queues to add the arguments `x-dead-letter-exchange` and `x-dead-letter-routing-key` and that's something I would like to avoid.

So my questions is:

1. **Is there a way to programmatically specify which is the `DLQ` where the messages should go after exhausting the attempts without re-creating the Queues? *Not using arguments x-dead-...***

I'm using Spring Boot 1.4.0.RELEASE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not via properties.

You have to override the listener container factory's advice chain with your own retry interceptor - built with a `RetryInterceptorBuilder` - instead of injecting

```
builder.recoverer(new RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer());
```

you need to inject an appropriately configured `RepublishMessageRecoverer` - as well as publishing to an exchange of your choice, it adds additional information (stack trace etc) to the message headers.

See the `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer` to see how the default interceptor is [built from the properties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer.java#L94).

The republishing recoverer is discussed in [this section of the Spring AMQP docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#async-listeners).